# How a video template can be used to replace with custom images/text on-the-fly using PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, flv

I am a website developer (php) and I have been given a task to develop a website similar to
http://ivipid.com/.

I need to make an identical website and I am trying to figure out how this can be done,
especially the part in which they use user-uploaded image files and text into the Video file and all this on-the-fly?

I know how to convert user-uploaded video files into FLV on-the-fly using FFMPEG but I'm not sure on how they (ivipid.com) manage to do this.

Comment: ImPossible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511207/anybody-has-any-idea-how-this-site-works-www-ivipid-com

Comment: then how they are doing this? [link](http://ivipid.com/)

Comment: The best part is they now have a http referer log from this question, so maybe they might be able to aswer for you!

Comment: lol, they not gonna tell us how they make it work.
I am still figuring out how to do this, cannot find any clue on google :( arghh

Comment: Where I work we've used Adobe After Effects and it's scripting language to produce slide show video's from a xml document that contains image links and auido tracks.

Comment: hmmm, i've worked with AfetrEffects as well but not with the scripting language. 
Is it possible to render a compilation on a web host?

Comment: We did have to use a Windows VM, so maybe it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Templater Bot from [Dataclay](http://dataclay.com) to achieve this.  From your PHP script launch Templater's command line interface using a function call like exec().  Check out Dataclay's [github cli-tools repository](http://github.com/dataclay/cli-tools) for more information on how to work with its command line interface.

Templater Bot is built for Adobe After Effects.  There is a basic workflow.  First, you prepare an AE project to be compatible with Templater.  It involves marking certain layers as dynamic whether it be text layers or footage layers.  Then you create a data source:  this could be a JSON object array, or something as simple as a Google Sheet.  Next, you setup a configuration file for the cli launch script.   The config file lets you specify output location, data source location, footage location, etc.  Finally, launch Templater and you'll have the versioned content that your app needs.

Full disclosure:  I am the lead developer of Templater at Dataclay.